# Nuxt problem Property was accessed during render but is not defined on instance

Tags: javascript, typescript, vue.js, nuxt.js

I try to do cards with blog posts. I made a component Post and inserted it into code. But is works as shown in the picture. And shows that. How to insert text into the cards? Now all the text in attributes. I just started studying vue and nuxt and all of examples are not fit.

```
[Vue warn]: Property "title" was accessed during render but is not defined on instance.
[Vue warn]: Property "date" was accessed during render but is not defined on instance.
[Vue warn]: Property "text" was accessed during render but is not defined on instance.
[Vue warn]: Property "title" was accessed during render but is not defined on instance.
[Vue warn]: Property "date" was accessed during render but is not defined on instance.
[Vue warn]: Property "text" was accessed during render but is not defined on instance.
[Vue warn]: Property "title" was accessed during render but is not defined on instance.
[Vue warn]: Property "date" was accessed during render but is not defined on instance.
[Vue warn]: Property "text" was accessed during render but is not defined on instance.
[Vue warn]: Property "title" was accessed during render but is not defined on instance.
[Vue warn]: Property "date" was accessed during render but is not defined on instance.
[Vue warn]: Property "text" was accessed during render but is not defined on instance.
[Vue warn]: Property "title" was accessed during render but is not defined on instance.
[Vue warn]: Property "date" was accessed during render but is not defined on instance.
[Vue warn]: Property "text" was accessed during render but is not defined on instance.
```

```html
<template>
    <div class="post"><div><b>{{ title }}</b></div><div><small><i>{{ date }}</i></small></div><div>{{ text }}</div></div>
</template>
```

```js
export default Vue.component('Post', {
    props: {
        id: number,
        date: Date,
        title: string,
        text: string
    }
});
```

```
<script setup lang="ts">
import Post from '~/components/Post.vue';

let posts = [
        {
            id: 1,
            date: new Date(),
            title: 'Title1',
            text: 'Asdns fdj d k hje jfaj fg fhbvjshefbvjv djfkenkn f  fj fdnkveklnelncln  jvjnjerejknkj'
        },
        {
            id: 2,
            date: new Date(),
            title: 'Title2',
            text: 'Asdns fdj d k hje jfaj fg fhbvjshefbvjv djfkenkn f  fj fdnkveklnelncln  jvjnjerejknkj'
        },
        {
            id: 3,
            date: new Date(),
            title: 'Title3',
            text: 'Asdns fdj d k hje jfaj fg fhbvjshefbvjv djfkenkn f  fj fdnkveklnelncln  jvjnjerejknkj'
        },
        {
            id: 4,
            date: new Date(),
            title: 'Title4',
            text: 'Asdns fdj d k hje jfaj fg fhbvjshefbvjv djfkenkn f  fj fdnkveklnelncln  jvjnjerejknkj'
        },
        {
            id: 5,
            date: new Date(),
            title: 'Title5',
            text: 'Asdns fdj d k hje jfaj fg fhbvjshefbvjv djfkenkn f  fj fdnkveklnelncln  jvjnjerejknkj'
        },
    ]

</script>
```

```html
<template>
<div class="posts">
    
</div>
<Post  
        v-for="post in posts"
        :key="post.id"
        :title="post.title"
        :date="post.date"
        :text="post.text"
    ></Post>
</template>
```

I tried different forms of scripts in components, but nothing works.

Comment: Is this nuxt 3?

Comment: Yes, it's last Nuxt

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One of the right syntaxes of declaring a component in Vue3/Nuxt3 is to use the `defineComponent` helper:

```html
<template>
    <div class="post"><div><b>{{ title }}</b></div><div><small><i>{{ date }}</i></small></div><div>{{ text }}</div></div>
</template>
<script lang="ts">
import {defineComponent} from "vue"

export default defineComponent({
     props: {
        id: Number,
        date: Date,
        title: String,
        text: String
    }
})

</script>
```

Comment: It makes Error 500: Number is not defined, and in VSCode text of all file is red. For unknown reason text of all file becomes red, if I add tag <script>

Comment: Sorry, they should be capitalized, please recheck my edited answer

Comment: It worked. A little strange, but everything is still red underlined